# Style multiple animated views with a single shared value, React Native Reanimated

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

I'm fairly new to React Native Reanimated, using v3

Basically I am wanting to style the opacity for a menu button based on which component is currently focused.

I have this:

```
    type clist = 'one' | 'two' | 'three'
    const opacityOne = useSharedValue(1)
    const opacityTwo = useSharedValue(0.4)
    const opacityThree = useSharedValue(0.4)
    const [current, setCurrent] = useState<clist>('one')

    const onPress = (screen:clist) => {
        setCurrent(screen)
        switch (screen) {
            case 'one':
                opacityOne.value = withTiming(1, {duration: 100})
                opacityTwo.value = withTiming(0.4, {duration: 100})
                opacityThree.value = withTiming(0.4, {duration: 100})
                navigation.navigate('One')
                break
            case 'two':
                opacityOne.value = withTiming(0.4, {duration: 100})
                opacityTwo.value = withTiming(1, {duration: 100})
                opacityThree.value = withTiming(0.4, {duration: 100})
                navigation.navigate('Two')
                break
            case 'three':
                opacityOne.value = withTiming(0.4, {duration: 100})
                opacityTwo.value = withTiming(0.4, {duration: 100})
                opacityThree.value = withTiming(1, {duration: 100})
                navigation.navigate('Three')
                break
        }
    }
```

I'm curious to know if there is a way to compute `opacity` based on the `current` state instead of including three separate shared values.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a few different ways you can solve this.
You could use a custom hook combined with [useAnimatedStyle](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/core/useAnimatedStyle/), to derive the opacity based on if the current tab is selected or not. Something like this:

```
function useMenuButtonStyles(selected) {
    const menuButtonStyles = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
        return {
            opacity: withTiming(selected ? 1 : 0.4, { duration: 100 })
        }
     }, [selected])
     
     return menuButtonStyles
}
```

You'd then use the custom hook in your component like so:

```
const [current, setCurrent] = useState<clist>('one')

const button1Styles = useMenuButtonStyles(current === 'one')
const button2Styles = useMenuButtonStyles(current === 'two')
const button3Styles = useMenuButtonStyles(current === 'three')

function onPress(screen: clist) {
    setCurrent(clist);
    // do navigation here
}
```

This should clean things up a little bit I think!

Comment: Yeah, I thought about a hook. It would clean things up slightly, but it still creates three separate instances of animated styles. Normally I wouldn't use such repetitive code such as `one` `two` `three`, but the number of screens and buttons is fixed.